# Ideal way to create non-freezing UI for Socket-based Android app

Tags: java, android, sockets, asynchronous, freeze

I'm working on an Android app that uses `Socket` to communicate with my app server (written in Java as well using `ServerSocket`).

In a console programs that I used to make for client Sockets, I had a loop that keep running and process all the messages coming from the server (a series of `writeObject()` and `readObject()` to-and-from Object Streams of Socket) until a certain message comes (eg; `bye`) which terminates the loop.

As console programs doesn't involve any freezing issues, it worked fin there. But my app has an Activity which will update the UI based on messages coming from the server, which would obviously freeze if I follow same approach.

So what would be ideal approach to handle such infinite loop that keeps processing messages received from the server, without hanging up the game UI.

P.S.: I know it is irrelevant but, I'm exchanging data between Android app and Server in **JSON** format. Also, an example explaining the suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find this interesting, since you mentioned it: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Comment: That said, it does sound like you would want to use a `Service` over an `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask`s are meant for a single operation, while `Service`s deal more with continuous, long-term operations like the one you described. Just remember to unregister the `Service` when you exit the game, as `Service`s can persist even after your app closes if you aren't careful.

Comment: @AlexLockwood: I'm absolutely new to Android, how can I access my Activity components (View and Layout) from within Service? also, I have buttons on Activity UI, which has click event handlers, when tapped, they'll send some data to the server, in that case, how service will come in between as a medium to process-send and receive-process data to and from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Using of `AsyncTask` is recommended. `AsyncTask` is primarily used to do such type of server interactions. Also you may look to use `Service` to make continuous interactions with the server.

Relevant links:

For AsyncTask - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

For Services - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: I went through `AsyncTask` and I read that I'm supposed to keep that forever-loop inside its `dodoInBackground()` method, but I don't understand that if AsyncTask is to be extended in separate class, How can I access my main activity methods from there?

Comment: You can use the `publishProgress()` method within the `doInBackground()` to update your UI. `publishProgress()` will internally call `onProgressUpdate()` which runs on a UI thread.

Comment: I don't get how I can access Views and Layouts of my main activity with `publishProgress()`. :-/

Comment: The OP mentioned a "loop" and "continuous fetching from a server"... an `AsyncTask` wouldn't accomplish this. You would use an `AsyncTask` for a single http request, or remote database connection maybe, but not for a continuous, long-term connection.

Comment: If you have your own class which extends `AsyncTask` you can always pass reference of your activity using the constructor of this class.

Comment: @AlexLockwood why can't I have a `while` loop running and use `publishProgress()` as and when I receive data to update UI. Though I fully agree that using `Service` is a better option, you can still use `AsyncTask` wisely to solve the problem.

Comment: Based on comments by @AlexLockwood, it sure looks like `Service` is more preferable over `AsyncTask` as my app will remain processing data coming from the server for indefinite time period.

Comment: @ArunGeorge, an `AsyncTask` belongs to the current `Activity`... so you'd be limited to working *only* within that `Activity` and nothing more (i.e. if you left the `Activity`, the system would cancel the `AsyncTask`). Even if this wasn't the case for the OP, it's still good practice to use the two classes the way they were meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for this on its own thread purely for networking and data processing.

You can then bind this service into your main application and send receive messages from/to it. Here is a fairly nice tutorial on the subject: [Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)